# jQueryUI Slider with dynamic php values

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, slider

I have got a slider in place that i want to have show a difference between 2 values from a MySQL database, what i have so far seems to be off slightly, here is my code.

PHP Code:

```
$warOffenderRespect = $r['warOffenderRespect'];
$warDefenderRespect = $r['warDefenderRespect'];


$totalrespect=$warOffenderRespect+$warDefenderRespect;


$percentage=round($warDefenderRespect/$totalrespect*100);

if($warDefenderRespect>$warOffenderRespect)
{
    $max = $warDefenderRespect;
    $value = $warOffenderRespect;
    $range='max';
}
else
{
    $max = $warOffenderRespect; 
    $value = $warDefenderRespect;
    $range='min';
}
```

JS Code:

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range<?php echo $slidercnt; ?>" ).slider({
  range: "<?php echo $range; ?>",
  value: <?php echo $value; ?>,
  min: 0,
  max: <?php echo $max; ?>,
  /*
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
  }
  */
});
$('#slider-range<?php echo $slidercnt; ?>').unbind('mousedown');


});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="slider-range<?php echo $slidercnt; ?>" style='width:200px;'></div>
```

the slider is displaying but the accuracy seems to off quite a bit.

Comment: "the slider is displaying but the accuracy seems to off quite a bit." apart from not making any sense, this does not tell us what you are asking!

Comment: my apologies for not explaining better, if i show you a pic of the results maybe that will help a bit more

Comment: ooops didnt realise enter submitted the form :s  http://i1283.photobucket.com/albums/a546/mark_harris4/slider_zpse9f2ba31.png  as you can see from the image the values given have quite a difference, im not sure if its because of the large values or if my code is wrong but what i want is the sliders to show the difference.

Comment: I've put part of your example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkSL8/). I cannot see any problem, besides the restriction to using only the keyboard.

Comment: sorry if this sounds a bit daft, but what restriction to only the keyboard are you referring to